# CSV file column (empty string values to NULL)

Tags: php, csv, insert, null, whitespace

I'm trying to import a data set from a CSV file. This works correctly except that blank values don't get inserted as NULL.

Somebody try to tell me to use load infile function but I really don't get it can someone help me out in this one here is the code.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES[csv][tmp_name]); 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 

    if($data[0]){
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO faculty(FCode,FName,MName,LName,Gender,image_name,BDate,Title,Service,EmpStat,CollegeID,DepartmentID,dateCreated) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[10])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[11])."','$currentDate')") or die ("error in sql syntax" .mysql_error()); 


    }   
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Comment: Check if the column is empty and if so alias the column to a variable and give it a NULL value.

Comment: here is a sample of what the csv file contains http://imgur.com/K3g5lAJ if this helps